# Not able to select div defined in the container having inset shadow using Pseudo elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am not able to select the div that are placed in container having shadow defined using pseudo elements ::before OR ::after. After defining the shadow, the div are not able to be selected.

codepen "http://codepen.io/smkudale/pen/lvFCt"

I have even tried to use Z-index=-1, however this too does not work.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

CODE HTML :

```
<body>
<div class="content">
<a class="shadow">
<div class= "b1"></a>
</div>
<a href="www.google.com">
<div class= "b2">
</div></a>
<div class= "b3">
</div>
<div class= "b4">
</div>
<div class= "b5">
</div>
<div class= "b6">
</div>
<div class= "b7">
</div>
<div class= "b8">
</div>
<div class= "b9">
</div>
<div class= "b10">
</div>
<div class= "b11">
</div>
<div class= "b12">
</div>
</a>
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
  .content
  {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  border-radius:500px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:#ddd;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;

  }

   .shadow
  {
  display:block;
  position:relative;


   }


   .shadow::before
  {
  display:block;
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  border-radius:500px;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 9px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 9px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);  
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 9px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:0

   }


  .b1
  {
  width:125px;
  height:125px;
  background:green;
  margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
   display:inline-block; 
   float:left;
  }
```

Comment: where is the code you are trying ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply the code is :http://codepen.io/smkudale/pen/lvFCt

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question as well.

Comment: Can any one please help?

Comment: @user3480773 it is important to give code you are trying in Question so that users coming in future can understand the Question and then can find the Answer.

Comment: @Meer I am unable to paste the CSS here. I have attached a link of code pen now- please check

Comment: @user3480773 I dont see any ::before in your css but ::after

Comment: @Meer I tried both pseudo classes Before & after! both do not work

Comment: the <a class='shadow'> is not in the view of your circle what are you trying to give a shadow ?

Comment: if you give class to a <div class='b3 shadow'> the shadow shows up.

Comment: @Meer thanks for the replies - I took the concept from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856528/box-shadow-inset-not-working

Comment: Have you now the solution for your problem ?

Comment: @Meer No i am not able to select the box below the shadow

Comment: have you read it --> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp what :before does ? before you try to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are closing tags out of order.

```
<a class="shadow">
<div class= "b1"></a>
</div>
```

Should be

```
<a class="shadow">
<div class= "b1">
</div></a>
```

Comment: this does not seem working. Can you please check the codepen http://codepen.io/smkudale/pen/lvFCt

Comment: what are you trying to do here? :before does not work the way you seem to think it does.

Comment: I just tried to hack the idea from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856528/box-shadow-inset-not-working

Comment: I asked what YOU are trying to do. You say you cant selectd the divs. Select them with what? javascript? css? what are you trying to do here? Do you even know?